# How to open multiple instances of a Data aware form RAD Studio C++

Tags: c++, ado

I have created an application in `RAD Studio XE C++`, now I need to open multiple instances of a data aware form which I created with `ADO` connections, each needs to be data independent from each other.

I can open multiple instances of the form with this code:

```
TFR_Form1 *FR_Form1 = new TFR_Form1(this);
```

And not setting the form as active in the Project Manger. The problem is that any data changes on one form reflects on all the others.